# Creating a pdf reader for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I wanna make a PDF reader using C# for wp7. The problem is I am not finding much of head start so if anyone has worked on similar project please guide me, a few web links would be great! Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Answer (score 4):

You can start with http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/

1) but this library doesn't render PDF automatic, it's only parse PDF document, so you can implement your own renderer.

2) this library is not updating anymore - I can tell it because i'm an author an i'm lazy as hell :)

For the moment it's the only solution for Microsoft Silverlight. I currently working on other project, but it won't be soon.

Anyway, I can tell you this, right now - custom PDF renderer - is not an easy taks.